# dual boot windows 7SP1 & ubuntu desktop

Tags: dual-boot

My machine is a dual boot PC with win 7 SP1 (C:) and win 8 (D:) , both are 32 bit system.

I want to replace win 8 (on D:) with the latest ubuntu dekstop, so my dual boot PC will be win 7 SP1 (C:) and ubuntu (D:)

Can anyone tell me what are the steps I should take?

Thanks, BK

Comment: First, uninstall Win8. Then, install Ubuntu. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

first you need to have a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(latest version) 32bit iso file and next create a live usb using unetbootin

in this link how to create ubuntu live usb with unetbootin
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-unetbootin-to-create-a-live-usb-linux/

boot from the pendrive and select "try ubutnu without install"

u will go to a screen like this
[image]

there install ubutnu 14.04

continue with your installation untill u see this like in below image

[image]

this is very important select "Something else" by selecting this u can select the partition where ubuntu gets installed, after that u will go to

[image]

here select your windows 8 partition

identify it with its size, still cant find it then minimize the 'installation window' and press windwos it opens dash type "disks" open disks and see ur windows 8 number under "device number"

then select that partition at the 'installation window' and select 'change' & 'partition type as ext4' & 'mount point as \' & select format

select your hard disk /dev/sda at the "Device for boot loader installation" & install now

it seems too lengthy but quite easy

i hope this helps

Comment: How about these steps:(1)-remove win 8 partition using windows 7 disk management (2)-reboot from liveusb (3) choose install alongside windows in installation windows.